# Weight transmission protocol in Federated Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, protocols, tensorflow-federated

I am wondering, in federated machine learning, when we train our local models, and intend to update the cloud model, what protocol we use to transmit those weight? Also, when we use the tensorflow federated machine learning, how we transmit the weight (using which library and protocol)?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

Most authors of federated computation using [TensorFlow Federated](https://tensorflow.org/federated) are using the "TFF Language". The specific protocol used during communication is determined by the platform running the computation and the instructions giving in the algorithm.

For computation authors, TFF supports a few different instructions for the platform which may result in different protocols, for example looking at summation operations of CLIENT values to a SERVER value:

- [`tff.fedreated_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_sum) that indicate any particular protocol.
- [`tff.federated_secure_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_secure_sum), [`tff.federated_secure_sum_bitwidth`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_secure_sum_bitwidth), and [`tfffederated_secure_modular_sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_secure_modular_sum) all use a secure protocol such that the server cannot learn the value of an individual summand, only the aggregate summation value (https://research.google/pubs/pub47246/ provides more details).

All of these could be composable with transport layer security schemes to prevent third parties on the network from learning transmitted values, and depend on the execution platform's implementation. For example TFF's own runtime uses [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) which supports a few different schemes https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking about the protocol that can be used to transmit (upload) updated parameters from client to server and vice versa (download). If you are only interested to implement this procedure in simulation environment, I suggest you look into the following protocols:

- gRPC - a bit old and primitive but works almost in any case;
- Open MPI - slightly difficult to set up especially across multiple GPUs but in the end, you will be awarded a nice communication tool.
- MQTT (mqtt_s3, mqtt_s3_mnn, mqtt_thetastore) - a very nice and realistic (works in real scenarios as well) communication protocol but it accents more on reliability and therefore, sometime you may face disconnection due to some missing association message.

Nowadays, research and development are slowing moving towards PyToch. Therefore, you may look at more complete solution in the following link:
https://github.com/FedML-AI/FedML/tree/master/python/fedml/core/distributed/communication